# Kafka Consumer is not consuming messages from all partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I created a Kafka topic with 10 partitions and trying to consume messages through a single kafka consumer. However, kafka consumer is not reading messages from all partitions.  More specifically, its consuming messages from 5 specific partitions only.
 **Example :** Consumer is consuming messages from [0,1,2,3,4] only. And after restarting if it starts consuming messages from [5,6,7,8 ,9] then it will only consume messages from these partitions. 
Here is output of kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh command

```
Group|Topic   | Pid | Offset   | logSize| Lag      |  Owner
GRP1 | topic1 | 0   | 128      | 175    | 47        |  none
GRP1 | topic1 | 1   | 117      | 146    | 29        |  none
GRP1 | topic1 | 2   | 62       | 87     |  25       |  none
GRP1 | topic1 | 3   | 101      | 143    | 42        |  none
GRP1 | topic1 | 4   | 104      | 145    | 41        |  none
GRP1 | topic1 | 5   | 118      | 118    | 0         |   none
GRP1 | topic1 | 6   | 111      | 111    | 0         |   none
GRP1 | topic1 | 7   | 161      | 161    | 0         |   none
GRP1 | topic1 | 8   | 144      | 144    | 0         |   none
GRP1 | topic1 | 9   | 171      | 171    | 0         |   none
```

Does anyone know why its happening..?

Comment: Show an example of your consumer? You could also verify the expected behavior by using `kafkacat`.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but we have 32 partitions and it is only reading from partition 7.

Answer (score 1):

**Kafka Consumer recommended configuration**
To set up a single partition per consumer, Kafka configuration needs to be designed in a right way. I would advise that you should have equal number of partitions per single threaded consumer per topic.
This means if you want to set up 5 consumer exclusively consuming single partition, you have to create topic having 5 partitions. In your case you might have to reduce the number of partitions using `./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:9092 --alter --topic testKafka --partitions 5` command.

As per your question, since topic is getting consumed partially, the consumers might have been configured into consumer groups. Another consumer in same group might be consuming remaining partitions & since the consumers are less than partitions, the partitions are inactive.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue this week while using [spark streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) to read from a kafka topic with 32 partitions.  Specifically we were using the spark kafka streaming classes provided by apache  [org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.*](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/external/kafka-0-10/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010).

We were only able to consume from a single partition. The issue was because we were including kafka version `0.10.1.0` with our jar. Reverting to `0.10.0.1` fixed it even though our cluster is on `0.10.1.0`.

Comment: I was getting this issue because of two instances of consumer, which were getting created due to some deployment issue. it got resolved when i fixed build file. I am using 0.9.x jar.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like our issues were not actually the same.  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @NathanLoyer I am also facing the same issue my Kafka broker version is 0.10.2 and my Kafka jar version is 0.10.2. So should I use the older Kafka jar version .will this fix the issue or should I try something else.

Comment: If you're using the spark streaming kafka class, you need the jar to be the same version that is being used in spark.

Comment: any resolution on this? I am using confluent kafka 5.2.1 and have 100 partitions. Having 5 consumers in a single consumer group  gets messages only from 5 partitions. messages from other partitions aren't consumed. If I increase consumers count, then messages are coming from partition is increasing. i.e 15 consumers, 15 partitions only. remaing 85 aren't get consumed.
I am using python consumer. 
ideally multiple partitions should get assigned to each consumer and in round robin fashion messages from all partitions should be given to consumer which is not happening.

Comment: I also faced this issue. I finally found that there was one stale consumer hanging in the background and that was acting as a separate consumer while my new process acted as one more consumer. When I killed that, everything went fine.